# CAD currency not allowed contact merchant - globalpayments

Tags: global-payments-api

CAD currency not allowed contact merchant - global payments
Tried changing to USD it works but not working for CAD
Is there any configuration to enable?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. You need to contact Globalpay account manager to enable CAD.